# Obtener el valor de un dropdown con optgroup de Bootstrap en ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, bootstrap

¿Alguien sabe como obtener los valores de un `dropdown` de `Bootstrap` con `optgroup` en `ASP.NET`?
Adjunto una imagen de referencia
Si le pongo al dropdown el atributo: `runat="server"` , para poder tenerlo en el backend, me sale el error de la imagen.
Parece que el asp.net no acepta que un select de html tenga optgroup

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muéstranos el pedazo de código que lo construye

Answer (score 2):

No creo que tenga un mapeo directo de este tipo de control a uno de asp.net, por eso el `runet="server"` no aplica

Deberias evaluar usar jquery, por medio de `$.ajax`, podrias invocar  WebMethod en la pagina aspx, en este caso los datos los tomarias con codigo cliente y los envias al servidor, no hay postback ni eventos.

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

[Calling ASP.Net WebMethod using jQuery AJAX](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx)

A donde apunto es que si vas a usar boostrap deberias evaluar dejar de usar conceptos de asp.net, sobre todo eventos, no se llevan nada bien.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando a un elemento `<select>` le pones el atributo `runat="server"` se covvierte en el WebControl [HtmlSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlselect(v=vs.110).aspx) que no admite `optgroup`.

Para conseguir, desde servidor, acceder a la opción seleccionada tienes dos opciones

**Opción 1:** Elemento select HTML puro y al valor seleccionado acceder a través de `Request.Form`. El inconveniente de esta opción es que queda un código bastante feo (sobre todo para establecer el elemento seleccionado desde servidor)

Código HTML:

```
<select name="CarField">
<option value="">-Seleccione una opción-</option>
<optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo" <%=SelectedCar == "volvo" ? "selected" : ""%>>Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab" <%=SelectedCar == "saab" ? "selected" : ""%>>Saab</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes" <%=SelectedCar == "mercedes" ? "selected" : ""%>>Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi" <%=SelectedCar == "audi" ? "selected" : ""%>>Audi</option>
</optgroup>
```

Código C#

```
public partial class _Default : Page 
{
   protected string SelectedCar { get; set; }

   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SelectedCar = Request.Form["CarField"];

       Label1.Text = $"El coche seleccionado es: {SelectedCar}";
   }
}
```

**Opción 2**: Implementar un WebControl. En este artículo (en inglés) "[ADDING GROUPS TO THE ASP.NET DROPDOWNLIST CONTROL](http://danashurst.com/adding-groups-to-the-asp-net-dropdownlist-control/)" tienes un ejemplo de implementación. *Esta sería la opción recomendada, sobre todo para tener un código mas limpio y reutilizable.*